# What happens to this Javascript code inside this php file when I use AJAX load() for the mail.php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> The `load()` method loads data from a server and puts the returned data
> into the selected element.

I'm a bit confused about this part of the code:

```
$(".form-message").load("mail.php",...
```

I have PHP and Javascript code inside **mail.php**. Both code handles errors.

Looking at the `<p class="form-message"></p>` element, the PHP code makes sense for that element because it changes the content depending on the user's input.

But for the Javascript code, there's nothing there pertaining to the `<p class="form-message"></p>` element to manipulates its content.

So I was wondering, if I load a PHP file like this to `<p>` element:

> $(".form-message").load("mail.php, ...

...and it contains Javascript code that has nothing to do with that `<p> element`, what happens to that JS code then?

Will it executes just like a normal Javascript code?

**index.php**

```
<script>
        $ (document) .ready (function() {
            $("form") .submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                var name = $("#mail-name").val();
                var email = $("#mail-email").val();
                var gender = $("#mail-gender").val();
                var message = $("#mail-message").val();
                var submit = $(“"#mail-submit").val();
                $(".form-message").load("mail.php", {
                    name: name;
                    email: email,
                    gender: gender,
                    message: message,
                    submit: submit

                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="mail.php" method="POST")>
    <input id="mail-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
    <br>
    <input id="mail-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <br>
    <select id="mail-gender" name="gender">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <textarea id="mail-message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Send e-mail</button>
    <p class="form-message"></p>
</form>


</body>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST[ 'name'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $gender = $_POST[ 'gender'];
    $message = $_POST[ 'message'];

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;

if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty ($message)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
    $errorEmpty = true;
}

elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'>Write a valid e-mail address!</span>";
    $errorEmail = true;
}
else {
    echo "<span class='form-success'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "There was an error!";
}
?>

<script>
    $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-message, #mail-gender").removeClass("input-error");

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; 2>";

    var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail; 2>";

    if (errorEmpty == true) {
        $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-message").addClass("input-error");
    }
    if (errorEmail == true) {
        $("#mail-email").addClass("input-error");

    }
    if (errorEmpty == false && errorMail == false) {
        $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-message").val("");
    }

</script>
```

*I found this code on this [Youtube AJAX tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7Sn-f36TGM).*